# SQL Server 2012: How to prevent duplication on records using a where clause

Tags: sql-server, duplicates

I have a database with three tables; items, item_unit and units. Items belong to one of 7 units. Creation of these tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE items
( 
itemID  int PRIMARY KEY,
itemDefinition varchar (150)
)

CREATE TABLE units
(
unitID int PRIMARY KEY,
unitName varchar(25)
)

CREATE item_Units
(
 itemID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES items(itemID),
 unitID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES units(unitID),
 PRIMARY KEY(itemID, unitID)
)
```

The scenario is, items that belong to the same unit cannot have the same definition. I know it is possible to create indexes and constraints on tables to restrict duplication but is it possible to do this as it relates to this scenario?

Comment: The item definition couldn't be stored at the `Items` base table level. That unique definition is based on the relationship between `Items` and `Units`. It'd have to be stored on a table relating the two, and made part of the unique key. You might as well just have two tables. `Items` should have a foreign key to `Units` and the linking table is unnecessary. Pretty sure that should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your scenario, the schema should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE items
( 
itemID  int PRIMARY KEY,
itemDefinition varchar (150) not null
)

CREATE TABLE units
(
unitID int PRIMARY KEY,
unitName varchar(25) not null
)

CREATE TABLE item_Units
(
 itemID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES items(itemID),
 unitID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES units(unitID),
 itemUnitDescription varchar(200) null,
 PRIMARY KEY(itemID, unitID)
)
create view items_with_units
as
select i.itemId,u.unitID,
isnull(ui.itemUnitDescription,isnull(i.itemDescription,'')+ ' '+isnull(u.unitName,'')) Description
from items i
left join item_units ui on i.itemID=ui.itemID
left join units u on u.unitID=ui.unitID
```

This way `select * from item_with_units` will give you what you want.